# How to trigger Mapbox events from another Vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to move a map website to Vue.

The website works in vanilla JS, fetching JSON from a public API and building 1) a sidebar with a list of cards and 2) a map.

In Vue it seemed obvious that I split these two parts into different components, like so:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <CardsList :cards-data="this.info" />
    <Map :cards-data="this.info"  />
  </div>
</template>
```

Because Mapbox is only initialized within the Map component, I have a lot of trouble just to get some event handlers in my Cards List, since they're supposed interact with the Map. It just seems incredibly complicated for what it is.

What am I doing wrong? Should the Map be initialized on App.vue and the sidebar be the only component? Would Mapbox GL JS expressions like `map.getLayer` be available on the component?

Comment: you could communicate between the two using emit and handlers - or use vuex

Comment: Yes, but it is proving incredibly complicated. And on top of it all, any clickhandler within Cards does not 'see' Mapbox GL JS.

Comment: well, I don't know the ins and outs of your current page, I don't know, for example what the clickhandler is listening to, nor what it is supposed to do - and I'm not going to wade through your current site to find out - emit and a handler works fine for simple things, vuex makes more complex interactions simple - but, again, I suggest how to use either, as the logic in your site is unknown to me

Comment: No, I get that. I've been looking into emits, vuex, etc. But my problem is also about Map functions not being available to the Cards component. Am I doing it wrong? Or should I use emit/vuex and carry signals across components so I click on Cards and Map the map shows a popup?

Comment: yes, the latter seems to be one way to do it - another may be creating a plugin that makes any functions required in both Cards and Map available to both - but, I'm not really sure if that is going to be necessarily easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual pattern I use is to use an [EventBus](https://medium.com/@andrejsabrickis/https-medium-com-andrejsabrickis-create-simple-eventbus-to-communicate-between-vue-js-components-cdc11cd59860).

You can see an example of this [here](https://github.com/stevage/community-map/blob/master/src/components/FeatureInfo.vue#L29).

Comment: Thank you, but I'm using vue 3, and I don't think that's compatible anymore.

Comment: Yeah, it would be a good idea to mention if you're using a major new version of a framework which is only 3 weeks old.

Comment: You're likely to run into quite a few incompatibilities with such a new version. In fact, the official recommendation is not to adopt it yet for new projects.

Comment: Sorry for that omission. I didn't know v3 was that recent and I thought the changes were minor. Your answer is correct though I believe EventBus is as a method is being phased out.